# AIO Asynchronous I/O with a callback function -- looking for best way

Tags: c, asynchronous, signals, posix, aio

I'm trying to learn `POSIX` asynchronous I/O.  Below is an edit I have made to someone else's illustration code.  I am trying to understand a few things.

First, I have a busy-wait loop near the end that keys off of the `int` `read_complete`.  Is that an "acceptable" (safe, whatever, ....) alternative to keying off of the return value of `aio_error()`?  Also, I was thinking as an alternative to the busy-wait loop, there would be a way to put the main thread to sleep and have the callback function send some kind of signal that would wake it up.  But I can't figure out how to do that, if it can be done.

Finally, I'm trying to figure out how to get more info into the callback function `i_am_done`.  For instance, let's say I wanted to shove the input data into a buffer, or split it up between buffers, that the main thread could use later, and the buffers might be different with each call if I had multiple reads to do.  How could I let `i_am_done` know what the buffers are?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <aio.h>
//#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <errno.h>

const int BUFSIZE = 1024;

int read_complete = 0;


void i_am_done(sigval_t sigval)
{
    struct aiocb *req;

    req = (struct aiocb *)sigval.sival_ptr; //Pay attention here.
    /*Check again if the asynchrony is complete?*/
    if (aio_error(req) == 0)
    {
        read_complete = 1;

    }
    close(req->aio_fildes);


}



int main(void)
{
    struct aiocb my_aiocb;
    struct timeval t0, t1;


    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        perror("open");
    bzero((char *)&my_aiocb, sizeof(my_aiocb));

    my_aiocb.aio_buf = malloc(BUFSIZE);
    if (!my_aiocb.aio_buf)
        perror("my_aiocb.aio_buf");

    my_aiocb.aio_fildes = fd;
    my_aiocb.aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE;
    my_aiocb.aio_offset = 0;

    //Fill in callback information
    /*
    Using SIGEV_THREAD to request a thread callback function as a notification method
    */
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = i_am_done;
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &my_aiocb;

    int ret = aio_read(&my_aiocb);



    if (ret < 0)
        perror("aio_read");

    //The calling process continues to execute

    while (read_complete != 1) {}

    printf("main thread %s\n", (char*)my_aiocb.aio_buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wrt question 2; what is it exactly that you mean? you are effectively "shoving input data to a buffer" right now? Or do you mean that inside the callback you would copy the data to someplace else?

Comment: @vmt  I mean inside the callback I would copy the data to someplace else.  For another example, you can see that the callback sets the global variable read_complete to 1.  How could I give the callback a specific pointer to some other, probably local, variable that I want it to set instead?  Maybe, for instance, different calls to the callback should result in the setting of different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering question #2, simply define a data structure into which you store the additional data you need, and set `sival_ptr` to that. For example:

```
struct my_data {
    struct aiocb cb;

    // For demonstration's sake:
    int foo;
    char *bar;
    size_t quux;
}

// ...

struct my_data data;
data.cb.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &data; 
// Setup the rest of the struct and execute the read.
```

In the callback, you have access to the my_data struct now.

Comment: So that's how it works.  Thanks!  I am surprised at the scarcity of references on the general subject of AIO.  Do you know of any good ones?  I'll buy a book if I have to!

Comment: The man page for aio has an example which uses sigaction instead. I'm not familiar with the aio interface, however you could look into event loop libraries which give you far more control and features than the aio interface. libuv, libevent come to mind. Or, you can look into implementing your own as well.

Comment: And I would imagine the scarcity of references is exactly due to the popularity of either using existing implementations of event loop libraries, or the relative simplicity of writing one. Both libevent and libuv have plenty of examples, and if you don't need all the features (timers etc), there's plenty of examples of simple event loops using e.g. epoll (on linux), (p)select, etc.